# Zurb Foundation 3 Orbit events and callbacks?

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, orbit

I was wondering if the Zurb Foundation 3 Orbit Slider has any callback events?

I need to have a slider where every X slide, a message is displayed. I was hoping there was a callback when a new slide is shown/changed, so I could bind to that and increment a counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in their documentation? http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/orbit.php

`afterSlideChange` is available to you.

Comment: Wiseass.  I studied that page and I must've overlooked the one line at the bottom of a table named "options" where they decided to list an event.

Comment: @Steve Sorry. I'm jaded from the people who don't look for themselves. If you would have put that you couldn't find anything I'd have been less of an ass.

Comment: I get it, I understand.  I guess only I knew at that point that I'm the kind of person that *does* check first.

Answer (score 0):

use this
  $("#slidershow").on("orbit:before-slide-change", 
                  function(event)
                  {

```
      });
```